# How do I drill down and find out which System processes are generating lots (10Mb/s) of network traffic?

Tags: networking

**Symptoms**

- Every night around 7-9pm my **network traffic jumps** up from about 100 kb/s (with nothing upr or downloading) **to about 10Mb/s.**  95% of that is reported as the **System** process. And it stays there until I restart either my "server" (Windows 7 Pro) or my primary computer (also Windows 7 Pro).  (This does not affect other PCs on my network.
- Also when the system is in this state, **copying files between the two PCs is very slow**: takes about 10 to 100 times longer. Transfer rates drop to about 1 Mb/s or less. (I've gotten 10 Mb/s+ transfer rates routinely)

**What I've tried:**

- I've looked for items in the Task Scheduler on both computers and removed them, then restarted, and it happened again.
- Disabled every Process that didn't seem necessary (on Server and main PC). Didn't affect anything.

[image]

Comment: If it's the "system", then it probably a driver-level piece of software (antivirus perhaps? Perhaps even malware itself?)

Comment: Have you run a wireshark capture to see if you can work out what is being sent out ?

Comment: @Lawrence, I ran Wireshark but I can't see how to tell what process (or sub? system process) is generating the traffic, it just shows a to and from address (i see the IP and the device (AsusteckC_60, Cisco-LI...) but I don't know enough about WireShark to know which application is generating that. Any suggestions?

Comment: You won't be able to see which process is sending it out, however it will at least tell you whether it's traffic that's good, e.g. microsoft updates by seeing where the traffic is going to / coming from. If you send me a screencap of the wireshark I could try and have a look for you.

Comment: I figured it out the old fashioned way: I just kept deleting processes till the traffic dropped. Turned out to be my TrueImage backup. The backup was finished but with errors. I suspect (still need to test) that it was still (very actively) trying to continue the backup.